# ASP.NET connection string to JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, driver

I have a connection string from ASP.Net which I have to use in my Java Application, however, I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

This is the error I'm getting:  Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase;" using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (The connection string contains a badly formed name or value.)

I'm using Microsoft JDBC 2005 driver (somehow it selected 2005 when I created a new driver for my persistence unit using sqljdbc_7.2.1.0). I'm using SQL Server Express 2017.
I'm trying to figure out which part of the string goes in which field:

My string is               "Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Those are the fields I'm trying to figure out.
host: localhost ( Also tried .\SQLEXPRESS, doesn't work either  )
port: 1433
Database: MyDatabase
Instance name: ???
Username: ???
Password: ???

I also checked my TCP ports on SQL configuration, I noticed TCP was turned off and there was no port, I changed this to 1433.

Comment: Try with the latest JDBC Driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Your connection string doesn't match the connection info in your error message. You might check that... In case you're wondering how to specify a connection string you should go for www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: @PeterSchneider, the connection string is a string from asp.net, I'm trying to get it to work with JDBC in a java application

Comment: sqlserver defaults to named pipes if you don't use a port number.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256044/jdbc-connection-url-for-sqlserver-express-r2

Comment: You can't use ASP.net connection strings with a JDBC driver. You need to use a JDBC connection string for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver as documented in [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017). The problem with the URL in the error message is that it ends in a semi-colon, and that is not correct, the syntax is `jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently I had to move a .dll file, which I didn't know. For some reason my default port was 1434 instead of 1433, had to change that aswell.