# How to connect spring boot to sql server management studio

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

So, i want to connect spring boot to sql server management studio, to practice crud operations, however when I try it i get an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHDf4.png)

So, I have added the dependencies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91y7f.png)

I have added properties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmhPX.png)

Here is my sql server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjmRr.png)

Here i have created a database called product:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpT57.png)

I have also enabled TCP/IP: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuS5H.png)

And i also have set the TCP port to 1433: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp0ZW.png)

However i still get the same error, could some one explain me what is the problem and how can i fix it?

P.s I have not written any code yet, i just made an empty project with spring initilizer, and for now i just want to connect spring boot to sql server (so i just run a empty demo application)

I have also tried to connect to sql server with writing java code, however it also fails: [image]

Comment: Looks like a firewall configuration, to me. The error is a "Connection Refused", and it is usually related to the firewall that is blocking the connection. I'd suggest you check your firewall setup

Comment: where should i see firewall settings? and what should i change?

Comment: Hi, instead of images can you please post the actual text/code? E.g. copy-paste the contents of `application.properties` in your post not just add an image. It makes it easier for all of us.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is wrong. For Express you need to add the instance name on the end. Have a look at this question: [JDBC connection Url for SQLServer express R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256044/jdbc-connection-url-for-sqlserver-express-r2)

Comment: i don't understand with what should i replace my connection string can you tell me?

Comment: Should be something like `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=product`

Comment: backslash, not forward slash, to separate machine and instance names.

Answer (score 0):

A few things might be missing from your connection URL, for example :

- Port number
- Instance name
- Basic authentication

Change the URL to something like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-7HI4O73;user=Givexa;password=yourPassWord
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.properties` file try changing the `spring.datasource.url` property to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=product
```

Comment: Use port number or instance name, not both.

Answer (score 0):

please check your pom.xml and see if you are adding correct dependancy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).